# rubymine rails server wasn't found in project

Tags: rubymine

can anyone help me with this.
Power cut crashed by Ubuntu system and when I restarted Rubymine it said a bunch of  .xml files were associated project I was editing were corrupted and being rebuilt.

After hours of messing around I'm almost working again. However I get the message
 rails server wasn't found in project
and in the run ->  edit configurations dialogue the Ruby SDK is listed as none with no options in the dropdown.

The Ruby SDK is select in settings, I have the rails gem in my gemfile, and bundle show (outside of rubymine) shows rails 4 gem.

Other projects work in Rubymine ok so its something with Rubymines config of this project, I tried searching for all the files in with my project name in Rubymines config directory and deleting then to no effect.

If it was possible to delete the entry in Recent Project' in Rubymines opening dialogue this may fix it.

Comment: You can clear recent projects with File -> Open Recent -> Clear List. I'd be surprised if that were the problem, though. Try this: quit RubyMine, move .idea/workspace.xml out of your project directory, and restart.

Comment: @Dave Schweisguth thanks, but neither of those things helped

Comment: Bummer. At this point I'd just recreate the whole project (i.e. move .idea out of the way and start over). Usually doesn't take that long. You can always copy parts back into the new one.

Comment: @Dave Schweisguth, a variant on what you suggested. I searched for and deleted all .xml files in my project directory. Deleted them and it started working again. Whew. Thanks for your tip.